# Is it legal to profit from explaining a book's content?

Tags: copyright, youtube, legal-concepts

I was wondering if explaining a book's contents on a potentially monetized Youtube channel is similar to simply being a tutor or teacher if the book is freely available online via "pressbooks". The book is under the following terms:

> 1. Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.
> 2. NonCommercial — You may not use the material for commercial purposes.
> 3. ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.

I definitely plan to provide a link to the book, but it's the 'noncommercial' part I was concerned about. Also, would it be ok to also include the definitions mentioned in the book, or would I have to write it in my own words?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/McBAb.png

Comment: In the image link (which is basically useless), the phrase 'commercial purposes' is linked, but because it's a stupid graphic, we can't follow the link. What does it say about 'commercial purposes'?

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Just for example in [CC BY-NC 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/) the term "commercial purposes" links to the FAQ [Does my use violate the NonCommercial clause of the licenses?](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#does-my-use-violate-the-noncommercial-clause-of-the-licenses) Why don't you include that link in your question and explain in more detail why it's not sufficiently clear for you in your case. *Thanks!*

Comment: Also see [questions about **NonCommercial** in Open Source Stack Exchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/search?q=NonCommercial)

Comment: [SparkNotes](https://www.sparknotes.com/lit/#A-titles) have certainly done quite well from it. But "explaining" can mean many things with different relationships to the text - if I was explaining Wittgenstein's Tractatus I'd take a different approach to The Color Purple or Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language. Do you mean "paraphrasing" or "analysing" or "providing background"?

Answer (score 4):

### That licence does not allow you to do what you want

It’s a non-commercial licence and your usage is commercial (making money).

### You don’t need a licence to perform commentary or review of a book

Providing that you use as little material as necessary from the original work, commentary and review is one of the exceptions to copyright carved out by fair dealing in most English speaking jurisdictions.

In the USA, the fair use exemption is not so clear as it involves a four factor balancing test. Your planned use is in favour of being fair use, your commercialisation is against.